# Java get a group of user names

Tags: java

I've coded a program where there is like 5 people "killing" a monster, and i need a piece of code to get all of the members "nickname" (getName() ) and display them with a coma beetwen, how could I do that?

I guess I could do a for loop but ye, not sure how to add the comas beetwen then..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your players are in a collection, you can indeed use a loop, or you can use some 3rd party library, like [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
Joiner.on(',').join(players);
```

Or [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

```
StringUtils.join(players, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you do in your loop depends on the way you have this information stored and the structure you are using for things...

But an example would be:

```
 String namesList = "";
    for(int i = 0; i != 5; ++i){
        String name = users[i].getName()
        namesList += name;
        namesList += ", ";
        ... //do something else
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/91

Or if you can use [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (highly recommended as a tool in your belt anyway):

```
String nickname = Joiner.on(",").join(listOfMembers);
```